# Help with a multivariable limit involving absolute value

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, absolute-value

I have been self-studying multivariable calculus and I need help with evaluating this limit - if it even exists.

> **Problem :**
> $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,0)} \frac{|x-1|}{3y^\frac{2}{3}}$$

I think the limit might be 0, I am not sure, so far I have tried the problem like this :

> $$\text{Set } f(x, y) =  \frac{|x-1|}{3y^\frac{2}{3}} \text{ and suppose }$$ $$x=y+1 \implies f(y + 1, y) = \frac{|y|}{3y^\frac{2}{3}}$$ $$\text{ and as } x \to 1 \text{ we have } y \to 0 \text{.}$$ Now $$\lim_{y \to 0} f(y+1, y)$$ is 0, as
> $$\lim_{y \to 0+} f(y+1, y) = \lim_{y \to 0+} \frac{y^\frac{1}{3}}{3} = 0$$
> $$\lim_{y \to 0-} f(y+1, y) = \lim_{y \to 0-} -\frac{y^\frac{1}{3}}{3} = 0$$

After this I don't know how to proceed, how can I generalise this? Should I try to do some $\epsilon-\delta$ proof showing that the limit is 0? I am not even sure if this limit even exists.

Comment: Does not Exist. Every Path must give same limit. Here take Denominator Constant , then let Numerator tend to 0 : limit is 0. Take Numerator Constant , then let Denominator tend to 0 : limit is infinity. We can take some other Path to get some other limit.

Comment: @Prem What you’ve written is just wrong. You can’t keep either constant if the point must approach $(1,0)$.

Comment: I was not clear or not complete, but It will reach (1,0) : In one case, when x becomes 1, then let y goto 0 :  limit (A) will not change in the continuation of the Path. In other case, when y becomes 0, let x goto 1 : limit (B) will not change in the continuation of the Path. But, we already know that the limits A & B are not same. Hence we do not have to continue the Path till the End (1,0). In other words, my Paths are [1] vertical followed by horizontal [2] horizontal followed by vertical. Take Starting Point (3,3) & Ending Point is (1,0). Some other Diagonal Path will get Some other Limit.

Comment: Are there Some Z Examples where [ limx→0 limy→0 (Z) ] & [ limy→0limx→0 (Z) ] & [ limx,y→0 (Z) ] are all Not Same yet Limit [ limx,y→0 (Z) ] Exists ? @TedShifrin

Comment: @Prem In this example, you're talking about *setting* $x=1$ and *setting* $y=0$. Points with $y=0$ are not in the domain. This is quite different from the iterated limits. Yes, $\lim_{y\to 0} f(1,y) = 0$. But I don't understand how you deal with the rest. ... In this problem, you really need more interesting paths, as I discussed in my answer. Can you prove that if $\lim_{x,y\to 0} f(x,y) = L$ exists, then $\lim_{x\to 0}\lim_{y\to 0} f(x,y) = \lim_{y\to 0}\lim_{x\to 0} f(x,y) = L$?

Comment: (A) Well known : If 2 (or more) Paths give Different limits, then limit DOES NOT Exist. Here, Vertical Path & Horizontal Path are good enough to show this. (B) There are other Paths which we need not check because we have 2 Paths with Different limits. (C) You ask "Can I Prove", but I never claimed that. (D) You claim it is wrong to use V-Path & H-Path. I ask for Counter Example Z where the 2 Paths have Different limits, yet overall limit DOES Exist. If you can show one Z, then my Method is wrong. If no Counter Example Z, then my method works. (E) I may be wrong, but I must see Z. @TedShifrin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the limit *might* be $0$. You have indeed shown that limit along the line $x=y+1$. But consider the path $x=1+y^{1/3}$? Or $x = 1+y^{2/3}$. Or $x=1+cy^{2/3}$ for different values of $c$? Then you get different answers. So the limit does not exist.

$\delta$-$\epsilon$ proofs are good for proving the limit *exists*, but usually paths chosen cleverly based on the actual function you have will give you intuition about what's going on. Just remember not to limit yourself to lines — pun intended.

Comment: Oh, silly me, I should have checked more paths. Yeah, the limit doesn't exist for $x = 1 + cy^\frac{2}{3}$ for any (non-zero?) value of c as the left limit becomes $\frac{-c}{3}$ and the right limit becomes $\frac{c}{3}$. So overall the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Assuming $c>0$? Yeah.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with a two variables limit, we can naively say that if we can determine two paths along which the limits are different, then the limit does not exist.
It's clear that we wouldn't ever be able to analyse the whole paths, since they are infinite. But there are some that often occurr. For example, the straight lines path. We consider the restriction along one of the infinite straight lines passing through the point $(x_0, y_0):

$$y = y_0 + m(x - x_0)$$

If the limit will depend upon $m$, then the limit does not exist, since a change in $m$ will result in a change in the value of the limit.

Now we choose the line passing through the point $(1, 0)$ so that $y = m(x-1)$

$$\lim_{x\to 1, y\to 0} \frac{|x-1|}{3y^{2/3}} \rightarrow \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{|x-1|}{3\sqrt[3]{(m(x-1))^2}} = \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{1}{3m^{2/3}}\cdot \frac{|x-1|}{\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^2}} = 0$$

In this case, and for this path, the limit does not depend upon $m$, and this means we cannot say anithing. Indeed a more intertwined path could exist, where the limit does depend upon $m$.

Well, for example let's analyse a simpler path: $y = m$ and $x = m$, that is along two lines parallel to the axis, one at a time.

When dealing along $y = m$ we have

$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{|x-1|}{3m^{2/3}} = 0$$

When running along $x = m$ we have

$$\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{|m-1|}{3y^{2/3}} = +\infty$$

Limits are different, hence the limit does not exist.

Comment: Very misleading … the two-variable limit is not at all two separate limits.

Comment: @TedShifrin Could you explain better? I admit I am weak about two variables limits. Yet I thought the method of straight lines would fit (we cannot use here polar coordinates, for example)

Comment: You seem to be thinking that you can do $\lim_{x,y\to 0}$ as $\lim_{x\to 0}\lim_{y\to 0}$ or $\lim_{y\to 0}\lim_{x\to 0}$. Your discussion of the family of parallel lines looks a lot like that. You haven't proved anything there at all. Looking at lines (or any particular family of curves) through the point *may* prove that a limit does not exist, but it can never prove the limit *does* exist.

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh, well I did not thought about that. I mean, I know I cannot separate limits, it's generally not possible. I just thought to use what I did remember from lectures. Perhaps I remembered wrong. Anyway, I'm ready to delete the answer (hoping also to read some insightful answer of yours!)